# Acceleration of a Point on the Edge on a Rolling Cylinder

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, rotational-kinematics, rotation

Consider a cylinder with radius $R$ rolling without slipping to the right. The center of mass is rolling with a velocity of $v$. Consider the left most point, $p$, on the cylinder. What is the acceleration of that $p$?

A certain book suggests that other than centripetal acceleration, there is also tangential acceleration.

However, the following analysis seems to show that there should only be centripetal acceleration. If we let $v_{p-cm}$ be the relative velocity of point $p$ to the center of mass.

\begin{align}
v_p &= v_{cm} + v_{p-cm}\\
\frac{dv_p}{dt} & = \frac{dv_{cm}}{dt} + \frac{d v_{p-cm}}{dt}\\
& = \frac{d v_{p-cm}}{dt} &\text{since the center of mass is not accelerating.}
\end{align}

Which of these are correct?

Answer (score 1):

The equations you have presented are correct. Also, it is correct to say that the centripetal acceleration is the only acceleration. So, the total acceleration of the point must be only the centripetal acceleration which will be towards the right. I'm not sure why the book says that there will be a tangential acceleration. A tangential acceleration if found when there is an angular acceleration but since there is none here it doesn't make sense to have a tangential acceleration.

Comment: centripetal acceleration is pointing towards the rotation center, and in this case, this is the contact point and not the center of the wheel. The difference is this "tangential:" acceleration.

Comment: There is no tangential acceleration whatsoever in this case